# Do Cookies work on IPhone IOS and ANDROID using PHONEGAP?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cookies

I would like to know if I can store on a mobile device (IOS and ANDROID) a web cookies using PhoneGap (webview).

Please note, the cookie is a standard one, no third party cookies or similar.

In order to use PhoneGap and cookies I would like to know what I should setup in my Phone-Gap project.

Comment: You'll have to be a little careful with cross-domain issues here. Are you trying to share cookies between your server and your PhoneGap app, or just store data locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PhoneGap is running the HTML on the device itself, so cookies in **that sense** don't necessarily make sense. But if you are talking about AJAX requests made by your app to other servers, then yes, the cookies should work fine.

Comment: Hi Raymond thanks for your answer, I have a PhoneGapp app, in my use case a user should login in the App, UserName and Password will be verified using MS Active Directory. If a User is authorised he will receive a cookies so he does not have to re enter his pasword next time he use he app. Do you think PhoneGap could support this? Thanks